# Start new Xamarin service with IsolatedProcess = true

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, service

I have two problems I would like to solve.

First when I set `IsolatedProcess = true` `OnStartCommand` never trigger

Second problem is when I start my notification I get `$projectname$` in my notification for some reason.

Here is my service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Comic.Viewer.Droid.Services
{
    [Service(IsolatedProcess = true, Label = "ComicViewer.ChapterNotifier.Service")]
    public class ChapterNotifier : Android.App.Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            var NotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(MainActivity.CurrentActivity);


            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);



            while (true)
            {
                var favs = DataStore.Db.GetFavorits(DataStore.AppSettings.CurrentUser.Id);

                foreach (var item in favs)
                {
                    var update = item.Translator == Modols.Translator.W_World_Translator ?
                                 DataStore.Wuxiaworld.SerieUpdates(item.Query) : (item.Translator == Modols.Translator.Boxnovel ?
                                 DataStore.Boxnovel.SerieUpdates(item.Query) : DataStore.NovelOver.SerieUpdates(item.Query));

                    var message = "";
                    if (update.NewChapters > 0)
                    {
                        message += $"{item.SerieName} Has {update.NewChapters} new chapter";

                        var NotificationId = Helper.GetRandomId();
                        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(MainActivity.CurrentActivity, NotificationId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
                        var nb = NotificationHelper.GetNotification1(GetString(Resource.String.ApplicationName), message, pendingIntent);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O) StartForeground(NotificationId, nb.Build());
                        NotificationHelper.Notify(NotificationId, nb);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(18000000);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I start my service

```
public void StartService()
        {

            var intent = new Intent(_context, typeof(ChapterNotifier));
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                _context.StartForegroundService(intent);
            else
                _context.StartService(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use it as an Isolated Process? There is no reason unless you want to run some insecure code isolated from your own App. Also for the $projectname$ thing. Check your AndroidManifest and see what value it uses for the App name. Perhaps it is some placeholder you haven't filled in somewhere.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(18000000); freeze my application, so i want to create a new thread for the service. as for $projectname$ is some kind of bug i got after i upgraded xamarin.form. i did not have this issue before now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue with the Service freezing your App when starting it, you could do a couple of different things.

One of them being starting a Task instead of blocking the main thread.

So encapsulate your logic in a method like:

```
private async Task ReadFavorites(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // your database and notification logic here...
        await Task.Delay(18000000, token);
    }
}
```

Then in `OnStartCommand` you can kick it off with:

```
_ = Task.Run(() => ReadFavorites());
```

If you at some point want to stop this service and cancel the task, you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass along a `CancellationToken` from that into the method:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var token = cts.Token;
```

Then pass along this token into the started task:

```
_ = Task.Run(() => ReadFavorites(token), token);
```

This way you can call `cts.Cancel()` to cancel any tasks you don't want to run anymore.

However, something like this would probably be better done by using the `JobScheduler` API in Android, since you are waiting for so long between your checks anyways. This way you won't need a foreground service running all the time and showing a notification for it.

Comment: Thats i good solution but i still want to know why `IsolatedProcess` wont work

Comment: Probably because you haven't specified which process it should run in with the `Process` property.

Comment: your solution worked like a charm, even though i still dont understand why `IsolatedProcess ` did not work im still glad for the solution so thx